# Conditional Probability on multiple variables

Tags: conditional-probability, multiple-integral

I have problem when I try to evaluate $P(X_1+X_2<c \vert X_1<c)$, where $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent and identically distributed.

More generally, I want to find 
$$P(\sum_{k=1}^n X_k<C \vert X_1<C, X_1+X_2<C,\dots, \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} X_k<C),$$

where all the $X_i$'s are i.i.d.

I was trying to do the integration over the joint PDF, but in my case, it may involve high dimensional integration (maybe 12 dimension), and the boundary conditions also look messy to me. So I'm stuck and don't know where to start.

Comment: I think it equals $$P(\sum_{k=1}^n X_k<C \vert \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} X_k<C)=P(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} X_k +X_n<C \vert \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} X_k<C)$$

Comment: It depend on if $X_i$ is positive or not,is symmetric or not. I think your question has lack of information. to more accurate answer, need more information about $X$

Comment: @masoud thanks for the reply. The X's follow a log-normal distribution. Actually I am trying to evaluate a structured product, and I have to ensure that at all the time points the asset price does not exceed certain amount. So I don't think the conditional information can be omitted like you suggested.